# Cant Get Cookies to work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, scope

```
var app = angular.module('rjtApp',
 ['ngRoute','ngCookies']); 

app.config(['$routeProvider',
 function($routeProvider) {


  $routeProvider.

      when('/', {templateUrl: 'main.html'}).

      when('/About', {templateUrl: 'about.html'}).
      when('/Evo', {templateUrl: 'evo.html'}).
      when('/Evo1', {templateUrl: 'evo1.html'}).
      when('/ContactUs', {templateUrl: 'contactus.html', controller: 'projectCtrl'}).
      when('/NewProject', {templateUrl: 'new.html', controller: 'storeProjectCtrl'}).
      when('/Register', {templateUrl: 'register.html', controller: 'register'}).
      when('/Login', {templateUrl: 'login.html', controller: 'loginCtrl'}).
      when('/UpdateProject/:id', {templateUrl: 'views/edit.html', controller: 'editProjectCtrl'}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
```

I'm Using the loginCtrl, to check with SQL  and return a True or False variable.

```
app.controller( ' loginCtrl ', [' $scope ', ' $http ', ' $location ', ' $cookie ', 

function($scope, $http,$location,$cookieStore)  {   


    $scope.getFormData = function(data) {
        console.log(data.username);//getting data input by user
        console.log(data.password);//getting data input by user
        $http.post('php/login.php', data).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);


            if (data) {//row inserted

              $scope.insertMessage = "Data inserted";
              $cookies.cookieStore = (data);

            } else {
              // if unsuccessful, bind success message to message
              $scope.insertMessage = "Data incorrect";


            }
            //reset values in form to empty
            console.log($window.sessionStorage.token);
    })
```

Iit gives me this error:

> Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=ookieProvider%20%3C-%20%24cookie

and as soon as i remove the $cookie the error disappears.

I did link the angular-cookie script aswell, any help?

Comment: on your controller qualifier it should be same with parameter on your function

Comment: i changed cookie to cookies, still no luck

Comment: have you change both? on your function and on your qualifier?

Comment: there all the same , all set to cookies now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the angular-cookies.js file. It was not compatible was running 5.2 version beta

switched to previous version and worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

Injectable object should be `$cookies` instead of `$cookie`

```
app.controller( 'loginCtrl ', ['$scope' , '$http', '$location', '$cookies', //<-- change here
    function($scope, $http, $location, $cookies)  {  

        //other controller code should  be as is.

    }
]);
```

Additionally you are using wrong syntax for setting `cookie` which is `$cookies.cookieStore = (data);`, instead of which you should use `$cookies.get` & `$cookies.put` while getting and setting a data.

```
$cookies.set('myData', data); //use while setting data
$cookies.get('myData'); //use while getting data
```

Comment: i did change it , same problem

Comment: var app = angular.module('rjtApp', ['ngRoute','ngCookies']);  

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

Comment: app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$cookies', 
function($scope, $http,$location,$cookies) {

Comment: how if you are using $cookieStore instead of $cookies?

Comment: i dont really know the concept of cookies and whats the difference between $cookies and $storecookies, but it doesn't make sens that when i remove the $cookies in the controller the error is solved. Im trying to use the $cookies now, and im trying to set their value same as the data (True or False)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xq6rm758/1/) that shows a simple way to `put` and `get` cookies.

```
var app = angular.module('rjtApp',
 ['ngCookies']); 

app.controller( 'loginCtrl', ['$scope' , '$http', '$cookies',
    function($scope, $http, $cookies)  {  
      $cookies.put('myData', 'data'); //use while setting data
            var myCookie = $cookies.get('myData'); //use while getting data
            console.log(myCookie);
    }
]);
```

Comment: Mine is exactly the same, but giving me the same error

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.12/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24ookieReader%20%3C-%20%24cookies

Comment: @LukeCassar Can I look at your code? Looks like the ngCookies dep is not being met.

Comment: Yes sure, in which way do you want i send you the code?

Comment: can you give me your email, so i can forward you my code, or even project

Comment: @LukeCassar Can you put it on jsfiddle or plunker?

Comment: u want to exchange emails, and i send you the whole thing?